# Ajax call subdomain to domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cakephp-1.3, jsonp

I have some troubles with ajax cross-scripting request using jquery.
I'm in a subdomain named test.example.com and i'm doing a ajax call to www.example.com/action like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
url:"http://www.example.com/action",
type:"post", 
crossDomain:true,
dataType:"jsonp",
jsonp:"cross_domain_action",
xhrFields:{withCredentials:true},
success:function(data){}
});
```

The problem is that i dont know how to test if the request is an ajax one or not in www.example.com/action.

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and there is a component call "request_handler.php" with the function

```
function isAjax() {
    return env('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === "XMLHttpRequest";
}
```

I found that there is not that HTTP header in the request.

```
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

If you have any ideas :)
Thanks

Comment: You can pass a parameter 'ajax=true' in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's exactly what you use to test if it's and ajax request. I usually use:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
&& strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
{//this is an ajax request}
```

Comment: well, this is it :) thanks. But is it normal that HTTP header in the request doesnt contain X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually check the headers. Cake 1.3 provides this information in the controller's `$this->params` property:

```
$this->params['isAjax']
```

will store 1 if the current request is an ajax call and 0 if not. Check it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/967/isAjax).
.